# jquery hover image swap using 2 images in same div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use the shopify platform for a small commerce site. I have the majority of the site built however on my main collection page I want to have an image hover effect for the front/back of the item. Currently my html is output like this with the first and second item in the products listing in a div. It's working sort of . Basically I want to have the image fadein on page load and when hovered on fadeout then fadein the second image in the div, when hover leaves revert back to original image.

.html

```
<div class="image">
  <a href="{{ product.url | within: collection }}">
    <img src="{{ product.featured_image.src | product_img_url: 'large' }}" alt="{{ product.featured_image.alt | escape }}"class="img-responsive collectionItem">
    <img src="{{ product.images[1] | product_img_url: 'large' }}" alt="{{ product.title | escape  }}"   class="img-responsive collectionItem" style="display:none"/>
  </a>
</div>
```

.js

```
$('.collectionItem').hover(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut();
    $(this).next('img').stop(true, true).fadeIn('slow');
        }, function() {
    $(this).next('img').fadeOut();
    $(this).stop(true, true).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Comment: Side note: Repeating `$(this)` selectors is a waste of processing. Use a local variable (when minimised the code is also shorter as a bonus).

Comment: planned on that once I figured the best way to fade in and out properly without flickering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/49fpX/1/

You need to chain the `fade out` and `fade in` to avoid the weird results. It is also usually better to put the hover on an element hat will exist the whole time as some browsers do weird things when the hover element disappears:

```
function swapImg($container) {
    var $image = $container.find('img:visible');
    var $image2 = $image.siblings();
    $image.stop().fadeOut(function(){
        $image2.stop().fadeIn();
    });
}
$('.image').hover(function () {
    swapImg($(this));
}, function () {
    swapImg($(this));
});
```

Comment: making a separate function was the way to go. very reusable on the site this way too. Thanks a bunch I was banging my head against the wall.